# mod and rem in Maple

Tags: polynomials, maple

**I do not understand this statement "reduce the coefficient modulo 5 and take remainder"?**

Is the following Maple command to reduce the coefficient modulo 5 , which coefficient to reduce?

```
rem(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13, pmod(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13,5));
```

And why use 5 and 7 ? where do these integer come from?

I find a statement divide each coefficient by $q$ and take the remainder
but type command according to this statement is not correct

```
rem(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13, quo(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13, 5));
```

The following two also not equal `x^2y-xy^3+2y^2-2`

```
rem(pmod(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13, 5), 6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13)
rem(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13, pmod(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13, 5))/5
```

**What is the difference between mod and rem in Maple? Aren't they both remainder?**

Comment: Please reject my suggested edit for this; I did not notice it's maple code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you meant [`modp`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=modp) (which is one variant of the `mod` operator in Maple) instead of `pmod` (which does not exist in my version of Maple, or in the [MapleSoft online help system](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/)).

The difference between [`rem`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=rem) and `mod` is that `rem` does [polynomial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), while `mod` simply does ordinary integer division on the coefficients.  For example:

```
p := expand( (x-1)*(x+9)*(x^2-23) );
```

$$p := x^4 - 32 x^2 + 8 x^3 - 184 x + 207 $$

```
p mod 10;
```

$$x^4 + 8 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 6 x + 7 $$

```
rem(p, x-1, x);  # x-1 is a factor of p
```

$$0$$

```
r := rem(p, x^3-1, x);
```

$$r := 215 - 32 x^2 - 183 x$$

```
q := quo(p, x^3-1, x);
```

$$q := x + 8$$

```
expand(q * (x^3-1) + r);  # reconstruct p from q and r
```

$$x^4 - 32 x^2 + 8 x^3 - 184 x + 207$$

Comment: how about reduce the coefficient modulo 5 and take remainder? it sounds must use modp, but modp(a,5)'s result is not the same in the example, where is wrong

Comment: i guess my book's example is wrong, as another book's example is using pmod or modp that is correct